# Why isn't garbage collection being activated in my code?

Tags: php, memory, memory-leaks

I have a `foreach` statement in my code, where each iteration calculates huge amounts of data and goes to the next iteration. I run this code, but when I read the log, I see there's a memory leak error.

PHP.net says when this happens, using `gc_enabled()` is a good way to handle this.

I've added these lines to last line of the `foreach` block:

```
echo "Check GC enabled : " . gc_enabled();
echo "Number of affected cycles : " . gc_collect_cycles();
```

And this is the output:

```
Check GC enabled : 1
Number of affected cycles : 0
```

Why do cycles exist, but the affected cycles is 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are you didn't see "memory leak error", you don't just see those. What you saw is probably the allowed memory exhausted error, which means that your script went over the allowed maximum memory limit that's defined in php.ini. To change the limit, look at the manual page for [core php.ini directives](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php). You'll find `memory_limit` under **Resource Limits**.

As for `gc_collect_cycles()`, the function is still [undocumented](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php), which is a good hint to not use it. What you read is probably the [theory behind collecting cycles in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.collecting-cycles.php). What the function reports is that there weren't any cycles collected, which probably means no memory leak error message in the first place.

I would suggest you avoid garbage collection in PHP until it gets properly documented and you understand the basics involved.

Comment: thanks. got it. but still have error. i think i should shrink my long calculation to some parts!

Comment: "there weren't any cycles collected, which probably means no memory leak in the first place" That really doesn't mean that. In managed environments, a memory leak is created when you keep objects alive when they're not truly used anymore. Even a 1,000,000 GC collections wouldn't clear those variables. That's why they're *leaks*. Collecting only checks which variables aren't used and frees up the memory slots they previously occupied.

Comment: @YamMarcovic You're right but the answer is in the context of the question. I've rephrased the sentence.

Comment: The answer was imprecise and partly wrong, and it's good that you fixed it.

Comment: @Netmoon You could try setting a larger memory limit in php.ini and of course breaking up your calculations in less memory intensive parts.

Comment: @39596: do it by assign all of memory to it, but still problem!! therz just one way, break up calculation. thanks all